# How to add content to an html from jquery loaded in other html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to do something for a client.
I would like to make a content creator on an html file to be loaded in index.html for example or any other page.
So to be clear, for example im in editor.html creating an article with title and subtitle etc, and when i press a button every thing appears in index.html.
Is it possible to do it with jquery or maybe other tool?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think this will require some server-side scripting.

Comment: Yeah you will need to save it somewhere, like an sql database, and need server side code to handle that, for example php

Comment: You are looking to create what is called a CMS (Content Management System). Here is a beginner's tutorial - https://css-tricks.com/php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/